# How can I limit and sort the response from _msearch in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `_msearch` in Elasticsearch 6.4: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/search-multi-search.html.

I can send multiple search in one API call and get the combined response. I'd like to sort and limit the response. It can be easily done by adding `sort` and `size` parameter for a single query. But how can I do that in `_msearch`? Queries in `_msearch` is running in parallel so can I attach a `sort` and `size` after all queries complete?

Comment: Do you mind showing the kind of queries your running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_msearch` provides an API to run multiple queries in a single request, but those queries are independent and not related. The order of the queries responses is the same as the requests order, you have to correlate the responses to your queries (the `n`th response id for the `n`th query), so you can't sort the responses.

As you said, you can add `sort` and `size` to each of the queries, and control each response independently.

Comment: The maximum number of documents in the response will be the total `size` defined in each query right?

Comment: Right. The main _msearch response will contain array of responses. each response  in the array will have the `size` of the corresponding request from the requests. So the total docs in the response would be the sum of all `size` params in all the requests.